# dplyr: optional parameter in mutate_each

Tags: r, dplyr

I use the `dplyr` package in `R`. Using that i want to create a function like

```
require(dplyr)
aFunction <- function(x, optionalParam1="abc"){
    cat(optionalParam1, "\n")
    return(x)
}
myFun <- function(data, ...){
    result <- data %>% mutate_each(funs(aFunction(., ...)))
}
```

and then call it like

```
data = data.frame(c1=c(1,2,3), c2=c(1,2,3))
myFun(data) # works
myFun(data, optionalParam1="xyz") # doesn't work
```

when calling `myFun` all optional parameters should be passed on to `aFunction`. But instead the error `'...' used in an incorrect context` is thrown.

This is the same function without `dplyr` which works as it should work...

```
myFun2 <- function(data, ...){
    for(c in colnames(data)){
        data[,c] = aFunction(data[,c], ...)
    }
}
```

how can I achieve the same result with `dplyr`?

Comment: you are using a very abstract and contrieved example, what do you need this for and what are you trying to achieve? without this information all I can say is read about function operators in hadleys book and drown in the complexity of R's scoping rules madness: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html

Comment: @grrgrrbla with `Curry` from the `functional` package you can get this working quite straightforwardly. See my answer below.

Comment: thanks :), I am always happy to learn new stuff! if you have any links or suggestions on where to learn more that would be awesome!

Comment: @grrgrrbla but the article on function operators also looks quite interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mutate_each` function simply does not interpret additional parameters as parameters to pass on to the function. So, once you pass it to `mutate_each`, the optional argument needs to be set. You can do this using a functional programming strategy called [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying). Essentially, you create a new function, where the default value of `optionalParam1` is changed. You can do this using the `Curry` function form the `functional` package.

```
aFunction <- function(x, optionalParam1="abc"){
    cat(optionalParam1, "\n")
    return(x)
}

myFun <- function(data, ...){
    require(functional)
    special_aFunction = Curry(aFunction, ...)
    result <- data %>% mutate_each(funs(special_aFunction))
}

> data = data.frame(c1=c(1,2,3), c2=c(1,2,3))
> myFun(data)
abc 
abc 
> myFun(data, optionalParam1="xyz") # now works
xyz 
xyz
```